# How can I Create/Register a Component Template dinamically?

Tags: templates, components, editor, ota, palette

I'd like to know if it's possible Create and Register a Component Template dinamically.

I know that I can create via Component | Create Component Template, but I'm using ComponentEditor to create components in a Form and I'd like to register some of them via componentEditor.

Can I do that? If so, how can I do that, please?